# How to make an animated blob?

Tags: modeling, animation

Ok, I have never done any deforming/shape blending, and Ive been working primarily in Maya here but I thought you guys on Blender exchange might be able to put me in the right direction.

Im very new to 3d and I need to make a shifting blob - essentially taking 2 spheres that have to be 1 object (HAVE to be combined or just 1 object, its crucial for putting it into Unity) and moving them around within each other to make it look like a cartoon cloud.

I watched several tutorials on shape blending as Ive found out that this means distorting objects in an animation, but most of them deal with stretching 1 shape or face, not making bulges/moving around other shapes.

This is what I have in Maya (I could do it in Blender also) but when I go to Deform->Blend Shape, it won't let me create an animation because the last 2 shapes were created by combining 2 spheres.

[image]

I just need to bulge a sphere in an animation to import into Unity. I have no idea where to go. How can I do this?

Comment: If I got what you need, you should be able to achieve this using either a single object made by 3 separated spheres, animating them as shape keys (https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html) but I don't know about how Unity will like shape Blender keys animation.

Comment: Why not just have it as three individual animated objects that share the same material? You could also do this with Metaballs although I'm not sure about the transition to Unity in that case. Collada might manage but I don't think so.

Comment: Because I have a transparent material and overlapping makes it look bad.

Comment: Have you tried using shape keys?